# wince UI application Japanese looks Chinese

Tags: unicode, localization, windows-ce, typeface

0R3 GUI application is able to display text in many occidental languages and Japanese too. 
I'm able to switch languages runtime by redrawing all the texts changing the font by using CreateFontIndirect(). Since my application do not use at all WinCE controls and do not show any WinCE dialog, I did not localize my nk.bin. I just added

The font I'm using are: MS UI Gothic for Japanese and  Tahoma for all the others.

I'm working to support Chinese(Simplified) too.
Notice that I'm not interested in internationalization of WinCE controls since my application actually does not use it. I just want to use UI Gothic for Japanese text and SimSun for Chinese.

I added "SimSun & NSimSun" catalog item to my nk.bin and rebuilt.
After this my GUI application displays properly the occidental texts(Tahoma font) and Chinese text(SimSun font). Japanese appearance is no more correct because it seems that SimSun font is used in place of UI Gothic.

I'm using CreateFontIndirect() function to get font
//pLf->lfCharSet = SHIFTJIS_CHARSET;

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add manually the Japanese code page (932). See here a [list of code pages for windows ce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms921507.aspx), and here [how to enable additional code pages to a platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms930801.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But it seems that the Japanese code page is already configured: I found code 932 into nlscpg.txt file of my flat release. 

additional info: WINCE 6.0R3 running on x86 using Intel BSP 2.5

Comment: I forced pLf->lfCharSet = SHIFTJIS_CHARSET and what I get for Japanese is something like Gothic font but wider that Gothic UI.